# Regarding PHP form

Tags: php, html

I am working on my project I want to store my multiple selected option value in the database but when I select more than one option at one time that time my only last selected values stored in DB please help my where am I am wrong?
Here is my Code:

```
  <?php
  require_once('contact_fun.php'); 
  require_once('contact_banner_fun.php');
  $obj = new contact_banner();
  $crud = new contact_us();
  $banner = $obj->get_data_banner();
  if(!$banner){
  echo "No Banner";
  exit;}
  $path = 'http://localhost/THE_VELVET_WALK/contact/';
  $result = $crud->getData("SELECT * FROM tb_contactus");
  foreach ($result as $res) {
  $id = $res['id'];
  $name = $res['name'];
  $business = $res['business'];
  $email = $res['email'];
  $phone = $res['phone'];
  $message = $res['message'];
  $style = $res['style'];
  }
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {    
 $name = $crud->escape_string($_POST['name']);
 $business = $crud->escape_string($_POST['business']);
 $email = $crud->escape_string($_POST['email']);  
 $phone = $crud->escape_string($_POST['phone']);
 $message = $crud->escape_string($_POST['message']);  
 $style = $crud->escape_string($_POST['style']);
 $result = $crud->execute(" INSERT INTO tb_contactus(name, business, email, 
 phone, message, style,  update_dt)VALUES ('$name','$business', '$email', 
'$phone', '$message', '$style',  now())");
 }?>
 <form action="" method="POST">
 <input id="00N7F000001F2j6" name="name" maxlength="40" type="text" 
 class="materialize-input">
 <input id="company" name="business" maxlength="40" type="text" 
 class="materialize-input">
 <input id="email" name="email" maxlength="40" type="email" 
 class="materialize-input">
 <input id="phone" name="phone" maxlength="40" type="text" maxlength="40" 
 class="materialize-input">
 <select multiple id="00N7F000001F2kO" name="style"  multiple="multiple" >
 <option name="consulting" name="styling" value=""selected disabled>image 
 consulting</option>
 <option  value="1">styling</option>
 <option  value="2">hair & make-up</option>
 <option  value="3">designing clothes</option>
 <option  value="4">wedding makeover</option>
 <option  value="5">personal shopper</option>
 <option  value="6">corporate services</option>
 </select>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to specify in the name of the select that it will be an array like :

```
<select multiple id="00N7F000001F2kO" name="style[]"  multiple="multiple" >
 <option value=""selected disabled>image consulting</option>
 <option  value="1">styling</option>
 <option  value="2">hair & make-up</option>
 <option  value="3">designing clothes</option>
 <option  value="4">wedding makeover</option>
 <option  value="5">personal shopper</option>
 <option  value="6">corporate services</option>
 </select>
```

and then you can implode it if you want a string like this

```
implode(',',$_POST['style']);
```

EDIT :
change this

```
$style = $crud->escape_string($_POST['style']);
```

to

```
$style = $crud->escape_string(implode(',',$_POST['style']));
```

Comment: Hello can you tell me where I  have to use this implode function in my code.

Comment: MacBooc Thank you soo much.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use an array for multiple select options :

```
<select multiple id="00N7F000001F2kO" name="style[]"  multiple="multiple" >
 <option name="consulting" name="styling" value=""selected disabled>image 
 consulting</option>
 <option  value="1">styling</option>
 <option  value="2">hair & make-up</option>
 <option  value="3">designing clothes</option>
 <option  value="4">wedding makeover</option>
 <option  value="5">personal shopper</option>
 <option  value="6">corporate services</option>
 </select>
```

this is how tou get the data into your database :
.php

```
if(isset($_POST['styling']) && !empty($_POST['styling'])){
    $Col1_Array = $_POST['styling'];
    print_r($Col1_Array);
        foreach($Col1_Array as $selectValue){
        //show selected
                echo $selectValue."<br>";
    }
}
```